# spell check context menu missing in kiosk mode on Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, kiosk, google-chrome-os

I'm developing a packaged chrome app intended to run in kiosk mode that would require spell check functionality on some inputs.

The problem is that when the app is running in kiosk mode on Chrome OS all spell check functionality is missing from the context menu.

Here is a picture of the default context menu when **not** in kiosk mode:
[image: app running on Chrome OS outside of kiosk mode]

Note that the context menu in regular mode gives the option to change the language settings and gives spelling suggestions.

Is it possible to get this functionality when the app is running in kiosk mode?

**UPDATE:**
[I have reported this issue on the chromium bug tracker.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=683134)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try to modify the full sample of Chrome contextMenu provided in this [Github repo](https://github.com/orbitbot/chrome-extensions-examples/tree/master/event_page).

Comment: @noogui the question is about why the chrome built in context menu options are missing for Chrome Apps in kiosk mode while they are available in regular app mode. And if there is a possibility of enabling them for kiosk mode. These options are not something i added myself, they are available as default behavior with the exception of kiosk mode.